# How do I reference the Jquery file below in my web view controller

Tags: jquery, ios, objective-c

I have the following Jquery file but do not understand how to call it from my web view controller. I am looking for sample code to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>span {display:none;}</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p><input type="text" /> <span>focusin fire</span></p>
<p><input type="password" /> <span>focusin fire</span></p>
<script>
$("p").focusin(function() {
           $(this).find("span").css('display','inline').fadeOut(1000);
           });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at  [stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString%3a)
E.g.
if

```
<input id="password" type="password" />
```

, then you can

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$('#password').fadeOut(1000);"];
```